# Integration testing of Maven Plugin submodule

Tags: java, maven, module, integration-testing, maven-plugin

I have Maven project with multiple submodules. One of these submodules, let's say submodule `X` depends on all other submodules, as it is Maven Plugin that integrates everything else.

Now I want to use this Maven Plugin during `verify` stage in my parent POM to do real run of it over entire project (kind of eating own dogfood).

Unfortunatelly I'm getting error:

> The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference

So how can I make such dogfood integration test for a Maven Plugin submodule?

Comment: Simply does not make sense. You are checking parts of your builds with a plugin which is built by your current running build? Usually you should separate the build of a plugin and a kind of framework or whatever which is used by the plugin...Furthermore the question is what you really like to test..The plugin or something different?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, I want to use the Maven Plugin I've just build on entire project. Let's say you have Enforcer plugin that enforces e.g. Java 8 as minimum, and then you want to use this plugin over entire aggregator to project in some last stage to make dogfood test. All jars should be already build, so I don't see contradiction in my question.

Comment: @khmarbaise Actually I'd like to make kind of Maven Invoker run, but on entire real project, not on dummy one.

Comment: @khmarbaise you wrote "Usually you should separate the build of a plugin and a kind of framework or whatever which is used by the plugin". Can you explain why do you think it should be the case? If someone introduces bug in "framework" I'd like to know about it immediately and have a full feedback how it integrates. I don't want to wait for dependency to be updated.

Comment: What i don't understand what kind of plugin you are building which you would like to use on the same project? The example of maven-enforcer does not make sense to me as well, cause if i use maven-enforcer-plugin this plugin has been developer independent and tested independent of my projects in which i use it...If you like to use maven-invoker you might give a real example how it looks like (may be on github etc.) so i can take a deeper look and see what you mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would review aggregation and inheritance: they are indeed [two different](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance_vs_Project_Aggregation) concepts in Maven often used in combination but which can however be used in a complete separated manner as well.

In this case, your plugin submodule is certainly defined as a module in the aggregator pom (that is, it is a submodule). But I also presume the plugin submodule also has as parent pom the aggregator pom as well (that is, the aggregator pom is also the parent pom, which is a normal approach, but not always required).

Is the latter required? You could keep on having the multi-module/aggregator approach without necessarely having the aggregator as parent of the plugin submodule. As such, the plugin subModule would still be a module of the aggregator pom but it would not have as a parent the aggregator pom, decoupling it from it and as such breaking the cyclic dependencies.

Possible drawback: in the aggregator pom you were also defining common things (dependencies management, properties) required also in the plugin submodule. If the case, you would then need to duplicate/review these common settings only for the concerned submodule.

Comment: Yeah, I have huge amount profiles and common things in my aggregator POM, duplication is unfortunately not an option to me.

Comment: can you use a different version of your plugin over your own project? Example: you break the cyclic dependency as you mentioned you know how you introduced it; then you release a version; you introduce again the plugin usage on the same project but for its previous version. Cyclic dependency should not be there any longer.

Comment: @ADiMatteo yes, that's what I do now. But then I need to wait till next release to learn about newly introduced bugs. The whole point here is to learn about bugs/changes in behaviour before the release :)

Comment: what if in the aggregator pom you define a profile in which you re-define the modules removing the plugin subModule AND configuring the plugin to be executed: as such you would have a profiled custom build for this purpose.

Comment: @MichalKordas If you have a huge amount of profiles i would call this already a `Build Smell`...i would like to see a real example of this...

Comment: @khmarbaise any comments on the above?

Answer (score 0):

Small suggestion from my side. Cyclic means you have some transitive dependency in your modules. Can please check the dependency tree of your modules and resolve the circular dependency first.